# How do I fix my resource post and delete methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`ControlPanelController` aka control_panel_controller.rb is my main controller code in which I want to handle all the logistics. Picture class aka picture.rb is the model I use.

In my resources I have

```
resource :control_panel, only: [:index, :new, :create, :destroy], controller: 'control_panel'
```

rake routes shows me

```
   control_panel POST   /control_panel(.:format)     control_panel#create
new_control_panel GET    /control_panel/new(.:format) control_panel#new
                  DELETE /control_panel(.:format)     control_panel#destroy
```

Here is my ControllerPanelController

```
class ControlPanelController < ApplicationController

      def index
        @pictures = Picture.all
      end 

      def new 
        @picture = Picture.new
      end 

      def create
        @picture = Picture.new(picture_params)
        if @picture.save
          redirect_to control_panel_path, notice: "The picture #{@picture.name} has been uploaded."
        else
          render "new"
        end 
      end 

      def destroy
        @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
        @picture.destroy
        redirect_to control_panel_path, notice:  "The picture #{@picture.name} has been deleted."
      end 

    private
      def picture_params
        params.require(:picture).permit(:name, :attachment)
      end 
    end
```

in my `app/views/control_panel/new.html.erb` I use  `url: control_panel_path(@picture)` so I can post to the ControlPanel create method but it doesn't work. I get

**ERROR 1:**

> No route matches [GET] "/control_panel"

```
<% if !@picture.errors.empty? %>
    <div class="alert alert-error">
      <ul>
        <% @picture.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= form_for @picture, url: control_panel_path(@picture), :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
    <p> 
      <%= f.label :name %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </p>
    <p> 
      <%= f.file_field :image %>
    </p>
    <p> 
      <%= f.label :remote_image_url, "or image URL" %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :remote_image_url %>
    </p>
    <p><%= f.submit %></p>
  <% end %>
```

**ERROR 2:**
When I try to delete a resource from index. I get

> `Couldn't find Picture without an ID`

```
Extracted source (around line #22): 

  def destroy
    @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
    @picture.destroy
    redirect_to control_panel_path, notice:  "The picture #{@picture.name} has been deleted."
  end
```

Line 22 in that case is  @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])

so what's the proper way to fix my routes.. I am using resource instead of resources due to having only one control panel since it's an app for one single user instead of multiple ones

**EDIT:**
code for app/views/control_panel/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Control Panel</h1>
<p>Manage all your pictures here</p>

<% if !flash[:notice].blank? %>
  <div class="alert alert-info">
  <%= flash[:notice] %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<br />
<%= link_to "Add Picture", new_control_panel_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<br />
<br />
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Picture</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @pictures.each do |picture| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= picture.name %></td>
        <td><%= image_tag picture.image_url(:thumb) %></td>
        <td><%= button_to "Delete", control_panel_path(picture), method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger", confirm: "Are you sure that you wish to delete #{pi
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>


**EDIT 2:**
```

Got the delete working by fixing button_to code as such

```
<td><%= button_to "Delete", control_panel_path(picture.id), method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger", confirm: "Are you sure that you wish to delete #
      </tr>
```

Comment: How are you sending the delete request to destroy Picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ERROR 1**

You are getting the error because your app does not have a route corresponding to  [GET] "/control_panel". Add :show to your control_panel routes and show action to your ControlPanelController. Also remember that singular resource does not have :index route/action.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources

**ERROR 2**

You are getting the error because params[:id] is nil. `control_panel_path(picture)` does not set `params[:id]` because you are using `control_panel_path` and not `pictures_path`. Try passing `id` as GET parameter: `control_panel_path(id: picture.id)`.

Nested resources is also a good way to go: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Comment: thanks! singular-resources barely explained much heh

Answer (score 0):

It seems your route control_panel#destroy does not take id param.
Use "resourece**s**" instead of "resource" like below.

```
resources :control_panel, only: [:index, :new, :create, :destroy], controller: 'control_panel'
```

This generates route like this.

```
control_panel_index GET      /control_panel(.:format)
                    POST     /control_panel(.:format)
new_control_panel   GET      /control_panel/new(.:format)
control_panel       DELETE   /control_panel/:id(.:format)
```